# JQUERY .filter().text() doesn't work properly on hidden element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I hava a collection of hidden div, which i would take only one, by class name (class="asd").
.text() method seems to not work, even if is returned an object by the filter method. Others JQuery methods still don't work.
That's my code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert($("#vetrina > :hidden").filter(".asd").text());
});
</script>
```

html:

```
<div id="vetrina">
    <div class="blocco" class="1">
       the text i don't need
    </div>
    <div class="blocco-inv" class="asd">
        THE TEXT I WOULD GET
    </div>
    <div class="blocco-inv" class="3">
        the text i don't need (it is still hidden)
    </div>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
<style>
#vetrina{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: none;
    display: table-row;
}
.blocco{
    display: table-cell;
    margin: 15px;
    border: 2px solid lightgrey;
    position: absolute;
    display: inline;
}
.blocco-inv{
    display: table-cell;
    margin: 15px;
    border: 2px solid lightgrey;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}
</style>
```

Comment: what are you trying to do here it is not clear?get the text of the div with class `asd`? then use `$('.asd').text()`

Comment: You can not have multiple `class` attributes on the same tag, but your class attribute may hold multiple classes, separated by a blank: `<div class="blocco-inv asd">`

Comment: Yeah @guradio is right, why are you looking for somethin hard, when it's really easy ?

Comment: @guradio it won't work

Comment: @ElMapoMapo can you see answer with snippet it will alert what you need

Comment: Ok guys, thanks all, my mystake was the class html attribute....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert($(".asd").text());
});
```

```css
#vetrina{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: none;
    display: table-row;
}
.blocco{
    display: table-cell;
    margin: 15px;
    border: 2px solid lightgrey;
    position: absolute;
    display: inline;
}
.blocco-inv{
    display: table-cell;
    margin: 15px;
    border: 2px solid lightgrey;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="vetrina">
    <div class="blocco 1">
       the text i don't need
    </div>
    <div class="blocco-inv asd">
        THE TEXT I WOULD GET
    </div>
    <div class="blocco-inv 1">
        the text i don't need (it is still hidden)
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @ElMapoMapo close the OP by accepting as answer :) happy coding mate